# Open file under cursor which name starts from slash but force search path to the current directory?

Tags: path, file, open

Consider the case of `html` file that has a `form` tag with `action` attribute and value of `/login.php`:

```
action="/login.php"
```

In which case `login.php` will be searched in the same directory as a html file resides.

Can I configure `path` variable the way forwarding slash will force the search for file under cursor to the current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a function which strips the leading `/` off the name of the file.
Then assign that function to the `includeexpr` setting.

```
                        *'includeexpr'* *'inex'*
'includeexpr' 'inex'    string  (default "")
            local to buffer
            {not available when compiled without the
            |+find_in_path| or |+eval| features}
    Expression to be used to transform the string found with the 'include'
    option to a file name.  Mostly useful to change "." to "/" for Java: >
        :set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\.','/','g')
<   The "v:fname" variable will be set to the file name that was detected.

    Also used for the |gf| command if an unmodified file name can't be
    found.  Allows doing "gf" on the name after an 'include' statement.
    Also used for |<cfile>|.

    The expression will be evaluated in the |sandbox| when set from a
    modeline, see |sandbox-option|.
    This option cannot be set in a modeline when 'modelineexpr' is off.
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting an `'includeexpr'` solved the problem, all the credits are going to Chris!

I just would like to provide a few examples of setting up an option for further reference. I am using `echo` to see the result of the substitution before setting up a final expression. Considering example with `/login.php` file, we can remove forwarding slash with:

```
:echo substitute('/login.php','.','','')
```

or add a dot `.` before the filename to anchor the search to the current directory as:

```
:echo substitute('/login.php','','.\0','')
```

where empty part for `pat` (2nd field) will refer to the whole string, and thereafter referenced in `expr` (3rd field) with `\0` prefixed by `.`, resulting in `./login.php`. Once  expression is chosen, you can set an option:

```
set inex=substitute(v:fname,'.','','')
```

Comment: If it's really the leading slash you're after, try `substitute(v:fname, '^/', '', '')`